# Angular - Promise within Foreach Loop

Tags: angular, promise

Below code is problematic because it is not returning anything. How do I fix it?

```
public checkExistence(value: Item, tableName: string, schema: string): Promise<string>{
  var result = "";
  this.configData.forEach(element => {
    if(element.key.tableName === tableName && element.checkExist != null){
      let uiValue = value[element.key.columnName];
      let refTargets = element.checkExist.split("|");
      refTargets.forEach(target => {
        let targetTableColumn = target.split(',', 2);
        let table = targetTableColumn[0];
        let column = targetTableColumn[1];
         this.getRefData(schema,table,column).then((value: string[]) => {
          if (!(value.indexOf(uiValue) > -1)){
           result = result + table + "," + column + "|";
          }
        })
      });
    }
  });
}
```

the whole purpose of this function is to check the existence of `value[element.key.columnName]` in some column of some reference tables. There could be multiple reference tables to check (and hence `refTargets.forEach`).

Ultimately I want this function to return a string that represents the list of table/columns which do not contain this value.

Found this similar case but not sure how to apply it to mine.
[Angular chaining promises from foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773610/angular-chaining-promises-from-foreach-loop)

Starting to learn Angular and Promise, and appreciate if you can help.

**IF you think this function could have been written in a better way, please let me know. I will accept it if it works :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

**Explaination:**
Following code

1. Makes a `Promise` array where each `Promise` will resolve to `table + "," + column + "|"` string.
2. Does `Promise.all()` on created `Promise` array. This will resolve to array of  `table + "," + column + "|"` strings.
3. Return a `Promise` which will resolve to a string resulted concatanation of array of `table + "," + column + "|"` strings in step 2.

**Code:**

```
public checkExistence(value: Item, tableName: string, schema: string): Promise<string>{
            // var result = "";
            let promises:Promise<string>[] = [];
            this.configData.forEach(element => {
                if(element.key.tableName === tableName && element.checkExist != null){
                    let uiValue = value[element.key.columnName];
                    let refTargets = element.checkExist.split("|");
                    refTargets.forEach(target => {
                        let targetTableColumn = target.split(',', 2);
                        let table = targetTableColumn[0];
                        let column = targetTableColumn[1];
                        let promise: Promise<string> = this.getRefData(schema,table,column).then((value: string[]) => {
                            if (!(value.indexOf(uiValue) > -1)){
                                return /*result = result + */ table + "," + column + "|";
                            }
                            return "";
                        });

                        promises.push(promise);
                    });
                }
            });
            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then((results:string[])=>{
                    return results.join();
                })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code gives me error at `promises.push(promise)`, it is complaining about promises 'not defined' at run time...

Comment: Forgot to initialize promises at the time of declaeration. Now it should work fine

Comment: Very helpfull after wasting long time on this same.thank you